# What does "RF Cal" means?

Tags: terminology

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S5. When I entered in the dial `*#12580*369#`, it appeared some information about the phone. One of them is "RF Cal" (it is formatted like a date).

1. Does anyone knows what it is?
2. What does "RF Cal" stands for?
3. Where did this terminology come from? What organization/person coined it?
4. If "RF Cal" is the manufacturing date of the phone, then why not just call it the manufacturing date of MFD for example? Is it because there is a difference?

Comment: A quick search showed me, its manufacturing date, but not sure

Answer (score 3):

"RF Cal" stands for "**R**adio **F**requency **Cal**ibration".

For smartphones, it means "time of first power up". After assembly, some parts of the phone (e.g. magnetometer & proximity sensor, radio chips, and antennae) must be calibrated before it's correctly functional. It is slightly different from "manufacture time" because hardware calibration is done after the device is fully assembled. You can simply think it's "time of the end of manufacture of this device".

Comment: What about some references?

Comment: [A Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=rf+calibration+site%3aforum.xda-developers.com) can tell you most of these stuffs. Also check #46 of [this thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2466721&page=5).